# Can anyone tell me why my case statement return null(good)

Tags: sql, sql-server, three-valued-logic

I have a query return null(good) with case statements,but when use where statement for each case, have records in output .

```
select a,b,sysdate ,      
 CASE 
     WHEN a IS NULL  AND SYSDATE > b THEN 'O'
     WHEN a IS NULL AND SYSDATE <= b THEN 'W'
     WHEN a > b THEN 'Fail'
     WHEN a <= b THEN 'Pass'
   else 'good'
 END  as result
 from mytable
```

> a    |    b |      sysdate  |  result
>
> null |  null| 10-JUL-19   |good
>
> null |  null|    10-JUL-19   |good
>
> null |  null|     10-JUL-19   |good
>
> null |  null|   10-JUL-19   |good

I have ouput when I execute this query(or other two)

```
select a,b,sysdate  from mytable 
where a > b
```

**output(where query):**

> a         |       b     |       sysdate
>
> 10-APR-15|     06-APR-15|     10-JUL-19|
>
> 06-APR-15|     06-APR-15|     10-JUL-19|
>
> 02-APR-15|     01-APR-15|    10-JUL-19|

```
select a,b,sysdate  from mytable 
  where a IS NULL  AND SYSDATE > b 

select a,b,sysdate from mytable
   where a <= b
```

Comment: You can't compare some values with null values in SQL server, you need to have some values or do some isnull condition to avoid nulls

Comment: You get "good" because `b` is `NULL` and `a` is `NULL`.  So, none of the `when` conditions evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `where` statement gets `null` values, then it returns `unknown`, which ecludes record from resultset.

Read more about three valued logic in SQL Server (just google it :) ).

This is why you don't get any records. For example, comapring to `a` column, where `a` is always `null`, gives you no records in rsult.

You need to use `coalesce` or similair "`null`-preventing" functions.